# Facebook tabs reciving data using $_GET

Tags: php, facebook, tabs

is it possible for me to send data to a Facebook tab using get requests? or can I only post data through the iframe to the page that I want to receive the data and let the iframe load like that as I'm trying to using the Twitter Authentication through a facebook tab.

Also why am I not allowed to send data using a get request to a facebook tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use GET requests on a Facebook tab but you can pass data through the *app_data* variable.

Try this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE?sk=app_1234567890&app_data=MY_DATA
```

You can access MY_DATA through the *signed_request* parameter. More about *signed_request* here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/